# jQuery Validation errorPlacement. Showing error in the Console

Tags: jquery, validation

folks. I need some help.
I'm trying to put the validation error message right next to my input file tag, but it gives me error in console. It's showing me a message, "TypeError: error.appendTo is not a function". This is a little piece of my code

```
$("#foto").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    extension: "jpeg|jpg|png",
    messages: {
        required: "Tolong Diisi",
        extension: "Harap Memilih Format yang Benar"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
    {
        error.appendTo($('#foto'));
    }
});
```

By the way, i'm using 'id' instead of 'name' which I've instantiated with

```
$("#formTambah").validate();
```

Comment: you can't place errorPlacement in the .rules(“add”) method, set it in validation.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment above: you can't place `errorPlacement` in the `.rules(“add”)` method, set it in validation:

```
$("#foto").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    extension: "jpeg|jpg|png",
    messages: {
        required: "Tolong Diisi",
        extension: "Harap Memilih Format yang Benar"
    }
});

$("#formTambah").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr("id") === "foto"){
            error.appendTo($('#foto'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok. gonna give a shot

UPDATE
wow, it works now. but it's not showing next to the element. Anyway, Thank you so much bro

Comment: @mending3 I have updated my answer - be aware that errorPlacement is a general Option for validation and you have to specify your "placement" behavior inside this method.